# Xcode method autocomplete show certain classes only

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

In Xcode, autocompletion shows me properties of the current class AND the base classes. Is there a way to show only the current class's properties?

Comment: No there is no way to achieve that.

Comment: I want this feature since for ever. File an enhancement request on radar (or you can duplicate mine: 22361502)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties are inherited so they are in your subclass. 
All inherited methods and properties are going to be available because there is no way for the system to know you don't want to show them.

File an enhancement request bug.

Comment: It probably is not feasible unless it were added to objective c runtime. The AST in Xcode would get bogged down by this going through deep class hierarchies. it might be possible one by one for clang via some new pragma directive but it has more problems than benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Current I don't think that's possible.